# How to search by key in hashset?

Tags: vb.net

I wanted a collection that would contain a bunch of unique strings. Hashset seemed to be the best option since it removes duplicates and is quick about it.

However how would i go about finding an item in the hash set? I could just loop through all the elements but wouldn't that defeat the purpose of being a hashset? Essentially i just want a dictionary where the key is the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hashsets are not used for searching. They are used to treat collection as a whole. You can use it as for what mathematical sets are used for: to create unions, intersections, or for checks of duplication etc.

The dictionaries and hashsets are similar in internal implementation, since they are based on hashtables. But sets do not have keys, since they are not allowed for the lookup of the elements. You must use dictionary for it. If you want to ask a set for an element, you will have to enumerate thru them all.

In the same way, you should not use Queues, stacks or linked list for looking for an element.

To have only strings in a dictionary you can use it like:

```
IDictionary<string, string dictionary =
    new Dictionary<string, string>();
dictionary.Add("Foo", "Foo");
dictionary.Add("Bar", "Bar");
string stringThatILookFor = null;
if (dictionary.TryGetValue("Bar", out stringThatILookFor))
{
    // Use stringThatILookFor, which has a value Bar
 }
```

Comment: It seems I cannot make sense of the question then (based on your reply and also Karli's reply to my answer. As such, I will remove the downvote and my comment. I don't want to argue, because we seem to be using different English here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356440%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
Dim hsStrings As HashSet(Of String) = {"a", "b", "c"}
If hsStrings.Contains("a") Then 'do smth
```

Comment: contains only gets me so far, i want to find the actual key itself to pass it out to other collections so that all string ref's containing "a" would refer to the same string

Comment: @KarliRaudsepp: HashSet finds a key in itself, because all elements are keys. If you want to find some other object by key, you need a dictionary. You last sentence in the question implies you want a hashset, so that's what my answer is about. If you described your need in more detail, I could provide a better answer.